# scientific table for the comparison of predictions

Tags: tables

In a paper I saw a table that looks like the added picture.
Unfortunately I didn't manage to implement it in latex.

[image]

That was my implementation attempt:

```
\begin{table}[]
    \begin{tabular}{lllll}
        \hline
        Error                          & Forecast &      &      &  \\ \hline
                                       & a        & b    & c    &  \\ \hline
        mean squared error             & 0.72     & 0.74 & 0.68 &  \\
        mean absolute scaled error     & 0.76     & 0.54 & 0.62 &  \\
        mean absolute percentage error & 0.79     & 0.71 & 0.61 &  \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

However, it does not look so professional; a, b, c do not have equal distances and the border under forecast is different.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm sure there's already a Q&A here that covers this, but I can't find a suitable one right now. So in a brief comment: To make the columns a specific width, you can use the `p` column type, e.g. `\begin{tabular}{lp{2cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}l}`. For the line under "Forecast", replace the `\hline` with `\cline{2-5}` (2-5 specifies the columns the line should cover).

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Also, the above advice will give you the general look, without any additional packages, but the spacing around lines will be slightly different from the picture - the original authors likely used the *booktabs* package that Alexandre mentioned. You might also like the [tabularx package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) - that gives you the `X` column type, which is a bit like `p`, but with an automatic width so you don't need to specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the *booktabs* package to make your table render this way.

Then you have access to commands more specific than `\hline`, such as `\toprule` (see the code below).

I also saw that you put 5 columns but you actually use only 4, so I corrected that in the code below.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{llll}
            \toprule
            Error                          & Forecast &      &      \\ \cmidrule{2-4}
            & a        & b    & c    \\ \midrule
            mean squared error             & 0.72     & 0.74 & 0.68 \\
            mean absolute scaled error     & 0.76     & 0.54 & 0.62 \\
            mean absolute percentage error & 0.79     & 0.71 & 0.61 \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Columns width**

However, you still have the issue of the column 'a' larger than columns 'b' and 'c'.

This is solved by replacing

```
Error                          & Forecast &      &      \\ \cmidrule{2-4}
```

by

```
Error                          & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Forecast} \\ \cmidrule{2-4}
```

**Centered columns**

Finally, you can center the three last columns if you want.

To do so, replace

```
    \begin{tabular}{llll}
```

by

```
    \begin{tabular}{l*{3}{c}}
```

And then it renders this way:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know the difference between `\cline` and `\cmidrule`? Both seem to work.

Comment: If you carefully look at the vertical spacing, you will see that it is to thin if you use \cline.

Comment: Ah, I get it, thank you again. Now it looks very good.

Comment: @AnneBierhoff I edited my answer because you can also center the columns. And you can do it very quickly for any number of column by using the short notation *{number_col}{alignment} in the mandatory argument field of the tabular environment.